# If $\Delta f\geq0$ for $f\in C^2(D)$ where $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex, show that $f$ has no local maximum in $D$ unless it is constant.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, multivalued-functions

So the Laplacian is the trace of the Hessian matrix and also if $f$ attains local maximum at for example $x_0\in D$ then $\nabla^2 f(x_0)\leq0$. This concludes that all eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f(x_0)$ are $0$. How should we proceed from here?

Comment: Isn't $D$ supposed to be bounded ?

Comment: @Surb Edited. Thank you.

Comment: It's true even if $D$ is unbounded. What should be added is that $D$ is connected.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis May you provide some hints if possible especially regarding to the assertion that $f$ is constant if $x_0$ is a local maximum?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $\Delta f\ge 0$, then
$$
f(\xi)\le \frac{1}{|B_r(\xi)|}\int_{B_r(\xi)}f(x)\,dx.
\qquad\text{Gauss Law of Arithmetic Mean}
$$
Hence, if $\xi$ local maximum, then $f$ is constant in the whole ball $B_r(\xi)\subset D$.

However, $f$ does not have to be constant on the whole of $D$. For example
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text{if} & |x|\le 1,\\
(|x|-1)^4 & |x|>1.
\end{array}
\right.
$$